# Where to put integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In the [documetation of Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#user-content-using-capybara-with-rspec) it's been said we should put our Capybara specs in `spec/features` . But when I use `rails generate integration_test user_pages` It creates a user_pages_spec.rb file in `spec/requests`. Which of these paths is the right place to put my integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spec/features is correct.

The generator is associated with the default Rails testing framework (which is not RSpec / Capybara).

Check https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/generators for Rspec generators.

Cheers!